# SlimScroll Error: Module build failed at ng2-slimscroll/index.ts

Tags: jhipster, angular2-template, angular2-directives, slimscroll

I have followed below steps Source from https://github.com/jkuri/ng2-slimscroll

1. Installation
   npm install ng2-slimscroll
2. Imported module like

   import { SlimScrollModule } from 'ng2-slimscroll';

   ```
   imports: [ ....................,
               SlimScrollModule,
             ......................]
   ```

   facing Error in nodemodules/ng2-slimscroll/index.ts like

   **ERROR in ./~/ng2-slimscroll/index.ts**

> Module build failed: Error
>       at new FatalError (E:\ReconWorkspace\AgreeGateway\node_modules\tslint\lib\error.js:40:23)
>       at Function.findConfiguration (E:\ReconWorkspace\AgreeGateway\node_modules\tslint\lib\configurat
>       ion.js:47:15)
>       at resolveOptions (E:\ReconWorkspace\AgreeGateway\node_modules\tslint-loader\index.js:35:64)
>       at Object.module.exports (E:\ReconWorkspace\AgreeGateway\node_modules\tslint-loader\index.js:124
>       :17)
>       @ ./src/main/webapp/app/test/test.module.ts 21:23-48
>       @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.module.ts
>       @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts
>       @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main/webapp/
>       app/app.main